# Is it legal to distribute customized Ubuntu?

Tags: customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Under what license is Ubuntu? Can it be legally modified and distributed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed)

I have made my own version of Ubuntu that I have customized using tools. I removed some application I didn't like, changed the login image to show my customized image, added the apps I like, changed other stuff etc.

The only thing I kept is the sources.list - this still goes to Ubuntu when I do the `apt-get update && apt-get safe-upgrade`

Is it legal for me to distribute my version? Or should I keep it for myself?