# Which free software license does Ubuntu use?

Tags: license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Under what license is Ubuntu? Can it be legally modified and distributed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed)

I would like to know which free software License does Ubuntu use for its releases.