# commercial redistribution of ubuntu

Tags: license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Under what license is Ubuntu? Can it be legally modified and distributed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed)

i'm making a custom ubuntu bootable live cd image by uck.
it includes some script and native binary.
of course, that follows GPL/LGPL license strictly.

is it possible to distribute my custom ubuntu image as commercial use?

if it's illegal for it,
is there any legal way to distribute it commercially?

or must i change other linux distribution, such as centos?
is centos ok to distribute commercially?

Comment: Somehow I am under the impression that any derivatives of Ubuntu cannot be distributed commercially (for a price). However, I will watch for updates on this post. I do understand that you have included some personally developed scripts and binary with your version of ubuntu..

Comment: You can redistibute Ubuntu what you can't do is use the Ubuntu brand on anything as it is property of Canonical. Read all the *Related* questions on the right.

Comment: Yes, but you must realease the source code of GPL components, and should not use trademarks of ubuntu