# Legal Question about Ubuntu

Tags: legal

So for many years I have been suggesting friends and family to switch to Ubuntu as it is my choice of OS, my question is this,

Can i offer setting up Ubuntu for small businesses as a paid job.

Now obviously I wouldn't be charging the customer for the operating system just the labor of installing and training etc.

But still is that something I am able to do as I wouldn't be selling the product just using my expertise to install it for a business.

Main reason is with the vast majority of small companies using XP that is as of now redundant I feel ubuntu would be a proven great alternative.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: As long as you are clear with your customers that Ubuntu is a free open source operating system and you are selling support and training.  Then there is nothing to stop you.

Comment: Yes my main selling point will be that it is open source so no paying for a licence as such, can run on low end pcs and that chance of a virus is much lower!

Answer (score 4):

You can ask money for installing and training. You are even allowed to sell copies of Ubuntu. See [Licensing](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) for more information. More information can be found in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed). When commercialize Ubuntu watch out with using the Ubuntu brands:

> Permitted use Certain usages of the Trademarks are fine and no
> specific permission from us is needed.
>
> **Community advocacy**.
>
> Ubuntu is built by, and largely for, its
> community. We share access to the Trademarks with the entire community
> for the purposes of discussion, development and advocacy. We recognise
> that most of the open source discussion and development areas are for
> non-commercial purposes and will allow the use of the trademarks in
> this context, provided: the Trademark is used in a manner consistent
> with the Usage Guidelines below there is no commercial intent behind
> the use what you are referring to is in fact Ubuntu. If someone is
> confused into thinking that what isn't Ubuntu is in fact Ubuntu, you
> are probably doing something wrong there is no suggestion (through
> words or appearance) that your project is approved, sponsored, or
> affiliated with Ubuntu or its related projects unless it actually has
> been approved by and is accountable to the Ubuntu Community Council

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy response! Will be preparing to offer Ubuntu as a solution for small businesses