# Can I make a Ubuntu distro and distribute it?

Tags: 12.04

Can I make my own Ubuntu distro and let people download it for free on my website

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what license is Ubuntu? Can it be legally modified and distributed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed) , [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Answer (score 1):

I think the user is asking if it is legal to do so. In that case: sure! thats why its free and open source. The only condition is that any changes or additions to the source code that you make, should also be free and open source. There are however some exceptions to that. They are related to some specific packages that are governed by different licences

[This](http://www.ubuntu.com/about/about-ubuntu/licensing) link should tell you what you need to know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can :

Just download **Ubuntu customization kit** .

Download it from here [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/)

To install it : `sudo dpkg -i name.deb (change name as package name )`

For more help watch this [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6J7EppxdnmI)

After all you can have your own ubuntu.iso file Uploaded to your Site !