# Why some wanted packages not pre-installed with Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, preinstallation

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I want to know why some very useful packages not pre-installed with Ubuntu?

I am talking about packages like:

- `ubuntu-restricted-extras`
- `gstreamer` & `libavcodec`or `vlc`
- `gksu`

Optional: `nautilus-open-terminal`,`unity-tweak-tool`, `hardinfo` etc.

---

**Is there any security or legal purpose?** Is it not available any-how in feauture?

Comment: ***Please post comment if any objection with question.***

Comment: You can create a custom iso http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd or this http://askubuntu.com/a/467999/265974

Comment: gdebi not needed because software center can do what it does, restricted extras, not everyone needs this bloated package, gparted not everyone needs it and it's not so useful as an application, more useful on a livecd where you ensure everything is unmounted, gtreamer not needed if there's vlc, you see you can't force everyone to use the packages that you like and you can't make ubuntu heavier than it already is. gimp? i'm not a designer, who wants it can download it, I'm a programmer, can i force everyone to use android sdk just because I  like it?

Comment: I'm just trying to defend the ubuntu dev decisions here, I don't use ubuntu, I use xubuntu, and the first thing i did after installing it, is removing things I  don't like including gstreamer.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the packages ubuntu-restricted-extras, gstreamer and libavcodec not being pre-installed on a default installation are purely legal than technical. These packages are non-free and the user has to accept a licence agreement (the EULA agreement). These packages will not be inducted into the default installation in future too, unless the licence changes.

Also, the packages gimp, nautilus-open-terminal, gdebi, unity-tweak-tool, gparted and p7-zip full may or may not be needed by many users who don't care to manipulate images(gimp) or their own hard disk(gparted), etc. However, these may or may not be included in future default releases depending upon whether Canonical feels the need.

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons:

Some of the packages are not included for possible copyright infringement in certain countries.

Some are not included to keep the initial image file not too big.

Others are simply not included because they are of use only to a relatively small percentage of users.