# Is the ubuntu system I am using distributed free of charge

Tags: system-installation

I installed my system with this file:

```
ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
```

md5:

> md5sum ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso

```
cab6dd5ee6d649ed1b24e807c877c0ae
```

I just want to make sure that this file is distributed free of charge, and is not a pirated copy. This might be a dummy question, but I am not familiar with the new system yet.

Comment: There is no such thing as a pirated copy: Ubuntu is free, both as in beer, and as in liberty.

Comment: That is incorrect: if you distribute Ubuntu without obeying the license terms, that is a breach of copyright and hence piracy.  Thankfully the license terms are permissive enough to allow wholesale copying and redistribution under the same license by anyone regardless of purpose. You'd have to do something like falsely claim you authored Ubuntu, or modify code without distributing the source, or try to distribute it under a different license, to break the license.

Comment: @psusi beer is barley free

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Under what license is Ubuntu? Can it be legally modified and distributed?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed)

Comment: Related: [This older post](http://askubuntu.com/q/17764/37165) asked on "How can I check the integrity of a downloaded Ubuntu CD?", in which the answers cover the part of question "make sure [downloaded copy of Ubuntu] is not a pirated copy [and indeed official release]".

Comment: The expression "free as in beer" means that I can give you a beer for free, but that is not the same thing as free as in freedom.  Specifically the freedom to examine, modify, and redistribute.  There is plenty of software that can be downloaded and used without having to pay for it, but they do not give you these *freedoms* with it.

Comment: sony got sued a few years back for violating gpl or gnu

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu is a free software. It is perfectly legal to redistribute it or/and modify it. You can this question for more info: [Under what license is Ubuntu? Can it be legally modified and distributed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed)

So when you see Ubuntu, even modified one, it is probably legal.Such popular distros as Linux Mint,Elementary OS,etc. would not exist if Ubuntu licensing didn't allow modifying and distributing it freely.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [according to here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/MD5SUMS), this file is the official version.

[source](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/)

[Ubuntu Hashes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes)

Comment: Just being pedantic: md5 is not a good hash algorithm. Someone could have changed the image in a way it will still have the same md5sum. That chance is very low but just to be sure, compare the sha256sum instead `756a42474bc437f614caa09dbbc0808038d1a586d172894c113bb1c22b75d580 *ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso`

Comment: @Germar Yes, according to http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/SHA256SUMS that shasum checks out. Again, the shasums and hashsums are all published on the following page: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/