# Is posting a system image legal?

Tags: disk-image

I will be using ubuntu for a research experiment at a university. I will be needing to put all meterials on a open science framework website, and am wondering if its legal to post a system image that was used to run it?

Comment: I would help by posting https://www.ubuntu.com/legal here, you can read everything about Ubuntu user rights.

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/questions/219/under-what-license-is-ubuntu-can-it-be-legally-modified-and-distributed

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

You are looking for option number 3 in the above link. It depends on how you going to post the system image.

Any modification to system image will requires approval of Canonical team before you distribute.

You are also bonded to the other terms and condition of ubuntu page.